# How to make two insertion all successful and failure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my recent project, for each user's payment, it needs to insert a Receipt and an Invoice into the SQL DB. I have 2 functions for it, InsertReceipt() and InsertInvoice(), so the code is like:

```
void DoPayment()
{
    InsertReceipt();
    InsertInvoice();
}

bool InsertReceipt()
{
   // insert to SQL with a ReceiptId
   // return true or false;
}

bool InsertInvoice()
{
   // insert to SQL with an InvoiceId
   // return true or false;
}
```

ReceiptId and InvoiceId have to be unique and consecutive here.

My question is, how can I do to make InsertReceipt() and InsertInvoice() all successful or all failure? Or I have to make a new function InsertReceiptAndInvoice(), and use SQL Transaction?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a stored procedure, you absolutely can use transaction. You can read about transaction in Microsoft docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/begin-transaction-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

With C#, you can use transaction with `SqlConnection`. Code example:

```
private static void ExecuteSqlTransaction(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        SqlTransaction transaction;

        // Start a local transaction.
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction("SampleTransaction");

        // Must assign both transaction object and connection
        // to Command object for a pending local transaction
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.Transaction = transaction;

        try
        {
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (100, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            command.CommandText =
                "Insert into Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (101, 'Description')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Attempt to commit the transaction.
            transaction.Commit();
            Console.WriteLine("Both records are written to database.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Commit Exception Type: {0}", ex.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex.Message);

            // Attempt to roll back the transaction.
            try
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                // This catch block will handle any errors that may have occurred
                // on the server that would cause the rollback to fail, such as
                // a closed connection.
                Console.WriteLine("Rollback Exception Type: {0}", ex2.GetType());
                Console.WriteLine("  Message: {0}", ex2.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.begintransaction?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1